# Why is my for loop printing 2 of my prompts at one time while using (scanner).nextLine();

Tags: java, loops, output

Is there a problem in my while or for loops by chance or am I missing something? First run through works fine but on the second I get this:

```
Enter course NAME: class name
Enter course HOURS: 4
Enter course GRADE: 4.0
You have entered class: jeff graves, class hours: 4 and, class grade 4.0
Do you want to continue:
y
Enter course NAME: Enter course HOURS:
```

It works just fine using `(scanner).next();` but then I can only take one word from the user and it will throw an error from the nextInt when it rolls over.

```
   public class GetGrades { //open class GetGrades

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
/**creating new instance of scanner named input to read user input*/
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  // create new instance of scanner object
        boolean repeat = true;  //boolean value for while loop holding array input
        String s;  // create string to store user input value for exiting loops
/** create 3 arrays to store course name, hours, and grades*/
        String[] name = new String[20]; //type string array for class name
        int[] hours = new int[20]; // type int array for class hours
        float[] grade = new float[20]; //type float array for class grade


        outerloop:  // set break point for nested for loops exit on user input 
            while(repeat != false)  {// while loop with boolean value to let user exit array input
        for (int i=0; i<name.length; i++)  { //for loop for name array

            System.out.print("Enter course NAME: "); //prompt user for input
            name[i] = input.nextLine(); //read next line value and store in array name
            System.out.print("Enter course HOURS: "); //prompt user for input
            hours[i] = input.nextInt(); //read the next int and store in array hours
            System.out.print("Enter course GRADE: "); //prompt user for input
            grade[i] = input.nextFloat(); //read the next float value and store in array grade

        /**Print line to console summing um what the user has entered*/
            System.out.println("You have entered class: " + name[i] + ", class hours: " + hours[i] + 
                    " and, class grade " + grade[i]);

/**prompt user if wanted to enter more grades, break loop on n or N*/
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue:");
            s = input.next();
            if ( s.equals("y") || s.equals("Y"))  { //open if statement
                repeat = true;
            } else  { //close if and open else
                break outerloop;
            }  //close else statement


          }//close for loop with i as count
        }//close while
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`input.next()` will read the next word. `input.nextLine()` will read up until the next time you press enter.

This means that when you write "y" and hit enter, you've input both a word "y", as well as the next enter, filling in both prompts at the same time and causing the next prompt to be written.

You can simply replace your `next()` with `nextLine()` when you ask to continue:

```
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue:");
        s = input.next();
```

becomes

```
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue:");
        s = input.nextLine();
```

thereby reading both the "y" and the enter. The next prompt is now free to accept new input.

Comment: **changed to input.nextLine() now it just blows through everything without a "do you want to continue prompt"... skips all the way till the end

Comment: Add a `input.nextLine()` after `grade[i] = input.nextFloat(); ` for the same reason

Comment: is there a way i can give you like a +1 or anything? very new to Stackoverflow

Comment: @JeffreyGraves Yay! There's a check mark below the answer score you can use to mark an answer as accepted. This awards 15 points.

Answer (score 0):

When you input the grade, for example 12.3 and enter, "input.nextFloat();" will only take "12.3" but not "enter", so "enter" will be taken by the next scanner.

In my opinion,

first, change "s = input.next()" to "s = input.nextLine()", but it will take the "enter" of previous scanner "grade[i] = input.nextFloat();", so, second, put it into a while loop as a condition. like this

```
while((s = input.nextLine()).equals("")) {}
```

therefore, it won't stop til get the expect input.

try this..

```
System.out.print("Do you want to continue:");
while((s = input.nextLine()).equals("")) {}
if (s.equals("y") || s.equals("Y")) { // open if statement
    repeat = true;
} else { // close if and open else
    break outerloop;
} // close else statement
```